# Cordova android scrolling/performance issues

Tags: android, css, cordova

I use the following CSS to create smooth scrolling for my Cordova app

```
.scrollable { 
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
    transition-property: top, bottom;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This works wonderfully on iOS, but for some reason on Android not so much. Overall performance with Android isn't close to what iOS is either, but it is most noticeable when scrolling. Any suggestions? I have `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on, but that doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android browser scrolling is always a pain, the performance is much worse than iOS. That's why [hybrid app frameworks like Ionic has introduced native scrolling to android](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/), which makes the performance much better. Ionic really rocks, but if you don't want to use it, you may do some Googling to find out more information about android native scrolling, or [read its source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic) to find out how they achieved it and port it to your project.

Another way to solve this problem is to embed [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) to your android app, it's a Chromium based webview. The downside is that the size of your APK will increase by 20MB, but performance and consistency on different versions of Android OS will really improve a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did actually embed Crosswalk into the app to improve performance. It also added support for Android 4.4. It does add a lot of size, but it makes a relatively level playing field to work with for Android, which is nice. I'm also doing some other performance things (like getting rid of box-shadow) to increase the performance and the difference was great!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)